# Giving ltr to MDC Switch not working inside a rtl MDC Drawer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mdc-components

The MDC Switch inside an MDC Drawer (RTL) has a thumb that is placed on the right instead of the left when it is switched on. I want the thumb to be at the left when it's off and at the right when it's on (I want the thumb to move from the left side to the right side).

I have tried tried adding `dir="ltr"` attribute to the `mdc-switch` element, but no luck.

```js
window.mdc.autoInit();
var drawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));

var button = document.querySelector('button');
mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(button);
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawer.open = true;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
<aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--modal" dir="rtl">
  <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
    <nav class="mdc-list">
      <div class="mdc-form-field">
        <div class="mdc-switch" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCSwitch" id="mdcAutoScroll" dir="ltr">
          <div class="mdc-switch__track"></div>
          <div class="mdc-switch__thumb-underlay">
            <div class="mdc-switch__thumb">
              <input type="checkbox" id="autoscroll-switch" class="mdc-switch__native-control" role="switch">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <label for="autoscroll-switch"><span class="mdc-typography--subtitle2 omnicolor">Log Auto Scroll</span></label>
      </div>
      <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-selected="true">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
<div class="mdc-drawer-scrim"></div>
<button class="mdc-button">Open</button>
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/avi2409/pen/VwLNpJr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The MDC Navigation Drawer is not really designed to be placed on the right side. Here's the [quote from this link discussing this specific issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1324):

> We've checked with our designers and this behavior isn't intended to
>   be supported for navigation drawer specifically, but there are plans
>   for more flexible components to accomplish this in the future.

I can see that because of this, you used a workaround to place the navigation drawer to the right. That workaround involves using `dir="rtl"`. Then, you wanted to invert the direction of the MDC Switch using `dir="ltr"` on one of the ancestor elements. However, according to the [docs](https://material.io/develop/web/components/rtl/), in *complex layouts ("complex" not specified)*, doing the above doesn't always work all the time. I tried doing that and it didn't work.

---

### Explanation

When the MDN Switch detects that its ancestor has the attribute `[dir="rtl"]`, it modifies two CSS properties: `right` and `transform: translateX(...)` (when checked). What can we do? We can alter those CSS properties back to when the switch does not have said modifiers. Doing this, the MDN Switch will correctly switch on from left to right and off from right to left.

---

### Solution

To do this, we can easily add another class `mdn-switch--ltr` to the container of the MDN Switch. The CSS properties that caused the MDN Switch to move in the opposite direction and start from the right are `transform: translate(-20px)` and `right: 18px` respectively. Overriding (either using a higher specificity or the keyword `!important`) these to the `ltr` values of `transform: translate(20px)` and `right: 0px` solves the problem.

Here's a working example (using a higher specificity). Do try running it.

```js
window.mdc.autoInit();
var drawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));

var button = document.querySelector('button');
mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(button);
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawer.open = true;
});
```

```css
[dir="rtl"] .mdc-switch--ltr .mdc-switch__thumb-underlay  {
  right: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .mdc-switch--ltr.mdc-switch--checked .mdc-switch__thumb-underlay {
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--modal" dir="rtl">
  <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
    <nav class="mdc-list">
      <div class="mdc-form-field">
      
      
        <div class="mdc-switch mdc-switch--ltr" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCSwitch" id="mdcAutoScroll">
          <div class="mdc-switch__track"></div>
          <div class="mdc-switch__thumb-underlay">
            <div class="mdc-switch__thumb">
              <input type="checkbox" id="autoscroll-switch" class="mdc-switch__native-control" role="switch">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <label for="autoscroll-switch">
          <span class="mdc-typography--subtitle2 omnicolor">Log Auto Scroll</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-selected="true">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
<div class="mdc-drawer-scrim"></div>
<button class="mdc-button">Open</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by rotating the switch. Here is the working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/patelashishpatel/pen/GRJVvBq?editors=1100)

```
// rotate the switch
.mdc-switch {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: center;

  // to keep knob shadow down rotate the knob underlay
  .mdc-switch__thumb-underlay {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
  }

  // for some reason the action region moves when
  // switch status changes. fix that.
  &:not(.mdc-switch--checked) {
    .mdc-switch__native-control {
      transform: translateX(25%);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: works but the movable slider button has the most part placed at the top not at the bottom.

Comment: Check the above codepen now. We can invert that too.

Comment: It works for me. https://codepen.io/patelashishpatel/pen/GRJVvBq?editors=1100. Do you wanna give it a hard refresh.

Comment: done but it's not working, I can't move the slider.

Comment: Here is a screen capture https://gph.is/g/Z5Ymw1o. I hope this helps. Not sure if it has to do with browser. It's tested on chrome and firefox.

Comment: it's weird, not working in chromium. Can you make a stack snippet here?

Comment: Oh i see what has happened. Please check the codepen here: https://codepen.io/patelashishpatel/pen/GRJVvBq?editors=1100. The interaction region was moved strangely enough to overlap partially on  the switch. I have applied the fix for that.